# Nomination blurbs overlap vote choices on the election page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Yet another design bug, on the election page.

To repro:

1. Vote for one or more candidates
2. Scroll the blurbs up and down (the chosen votes stay fixed on the right)
3. Notice the overlap between the blurbs and the votes.

Example (hopefully anonymous!):

[image: bug]

Answer (score 2):

Good catch - this will be fixed in the next build.